# Access token validation failure for AD graph API after using the token acquired from AzureRmContext in Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to make API calls to Microsoft graph API using Oauth2 to log in.

I tried to use AzureRm cmdlet to get the token for my account, so I can make the API calls, but the message "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience." showed up in the JSON response.

```bsh
Login-AzureRmAccount

$currentAzureContext = Get-AzureRmContext
$tenantId = $currentAzureContext.Tenant.Id
$accountId = $currentAzureContext.Account.Id

$tokenCache = $currentAzureContext.TokenCache
$cachedTokens = $tokenCache.ReadItems() `
        | where { $_.TenantId -eq $tenantId }

$accessToken = $cachedTokens.AccessToken
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get `
                 -Uri ("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me") `
                -Headers @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer " + $accessToken }
```

The following is the JSON response:

```bsh
Invoke-RestMethod : {
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "8429e520-401b-4382-adad-4f55bccbe752",
      "date": "2019-11-04T16:53:27"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the token in https://jwt.ms and see what is the aud claim. I think the token you get via AzureRm is an access token to the Azure Management APIs. The value for MS Graph is 'https://graph.microsoft.com'. You can use the AzureAD PS module to get Graph tokens. Also note that AAD is notthe same as MS Graph.